# ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model

I have the following code:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.params = params
        
        self.hidden_layer_one = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.params['e_filters'],
                                                       kernel_size=self.params['e_size'],
                                                       activation=self.params['activation'], strides=1, padding='same',
                                                       kernel_initializer=params['initializer'], use_bias=False)
        self.hidden_layer_two = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.params['num_endmembers'], kernel_size=1,
                                                       activation=self.params['activation'], strides=1, padding='same',
                                                       kernel_initializer=self.params['initializer'], use_bias=False)
        self.asc_layer = ASC(params=self.params, name='abundances')

    def call(self, input_patch):
        code = self.hidden_layer_one(input_patch)
        code = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(code)
        code = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2)(code)
        code = self.hidden_layer_two(code)
        code = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(code)
        code = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2)(code)
        code = self.asc_layer(code)
        return code

class Autoencoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(params)
        self.decoder = Decoder(params)
        self.params = params

    def call(self, patch):
        abunds = self.encoder(patch)
        abunds = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.08)(abunds)
        output = self.decoder(abunds)
        return output

    
    def train(self, patches, callback):
        self.plotWhileTraining = callback
        self.fit(patches, patches, epochs=self.params['epochs'], batch_size=self.params['batch_size'],
                 callbacks=[self.plotWhileTraining], verbose=0)
```

I get the error in the title,

```
ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call. 
Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or created outside tf.function. 
See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables for more information.
        
        
        Call arguments received by layer 'encoder_3' (type Encoder):
          • input_patch=tf.Tensor(shape=(15, 80, 80, 156), dtype=float32)
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'autoencoder_3' (type Autoencoder):
      • patch=tf.Tensor(shape=(15, 80, 80, 156), dtype=float32)
```

I read the documentation but I still don't know how to solve it.

I tried `model.build()` but I'm not sure where to call it.

Comment: You should not create new layers in `call` (dropout, batchnorm).

Comment: @xdurch0 so what do I do instead?

Comment: Create them in `__init__` like the other layers.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you are using same tensorflow layers (BatchNormalization etc.) multiple times in call method. You must change your code from

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, params):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.params = params
    
    self.hidden_layer_one = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.params['e_filters'],
                                                   kernel_size=self.params['e_size'],
                                                   activation=self.params['activation'], strides=1, padding='same',
                                                   kernel_initializer=params['initializer'], use_bias=False)
    self.hidden_layer_two = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.params['num_endmembers'], kernel_size=1,
                                                   activation=self.params['activation'], strides=1, padding='same',
                                                   kernel_initializer=self.params['initializer'], use_bias=False)
    self.asc_layer = ASC(params=self.params, name='abundances')

def call(self, input_patch):
    code = self.hidden_layer_one(input_patch)
    code = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(code)
    code = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2)(code)
    code = self.hidden_layer_two(code)
    code = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(code)
    code = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2)(code)
    code = self.asc_layer(code)
    return code
```

to this:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, params):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.params = params
    
    self.hidden_layer_one = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.params['e_filters'],
                                                   kernel_size=self.params['e_size'],
                                                   activation=self.params['activation'], strides=1, padding='same',
                                                   kernel_initializer=params['initializer'], use_bias=False)
    self.hidden_layer_two = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.params['num_endmembers'], kernel_size=1,
                                                   activation=self.params['activation'], strides=1, padding='same',
                                                   kernel_initializer=self.params['initializer'], use_bias=False)
    self.asc_layer = ASC(params=self.params, name='abundances')

    self.norm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.norm2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.drop1 = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2)
    self.drop2 = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2)

def call(self, input_patch):
    code = self.hidden_layer_one(input_patch)
    code = self.norm1(code)
    code = self.drop1(code)
    code = self.hidden_layer_two(code)
    code = self.norm2(code)
    code = self.drop2(code)
    code = self.asc_layer(code)
    return code
```

Same changes are also required in other classes